# asp net core 2.2 redirect url include %252F with apache 2.4

Tags: asp.net, apache, asp.net-core

I am using asp net core 2.2.0 and deployed into apache 2.4.18.

In the return url, it includes "%252F" instead of %2F. For example, https://my-server/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%252F

I have tried to use "AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode" but still not work for me.

Any suggestion to fix it?

Comment: Could you please include some code? From what you've given all I can tell is it looks like you've URL encoded `https://my-server/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=/` twice.

Comment: I guess this is a bug in the apache about rewriting. The same codes are working on IIS Express.